# Is there a way to create the pure CSS2 cross-browser triangles?

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

Like it's said in title, does someone know the trick to make the triangles with `CSS2` (not CSS3) without using images ?

Comment: by the way, why i'am getting `-1` ? just wondering, what i've messed up again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little request on a good website will give your answer :

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

```css
.arrow-up {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 
 border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
 
 border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
 
 border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. that's exactly what i was searching for. handy stuff.